# Neural Network With Sparse Output

Tags: neural-network, sparse-matrix, lstm

I have an interesting problem which can be reduced to this simple task. Consider a neural net (LSTM, or whatever) which will learn to copy sparse binary matrices with sparsity of about 1%.

If we look at the cost function of just guessing 0's for all entries it's going to be about 100-%sparsity, so you can get really high accuracy just by guessing all 0's.

Is there anyway to bump the neural network out of this huge local minimum by altering either the sparse matrix representation or the cost function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I see this has been in here for just shy of 3 years now, so my answer might not be the most relevant for you at this point, but for anyone who stumbles upon this question looking for the answer:

It very much depends on type of loss function, optimizer and activation function in use. I will be mainly speaking in terms of **classification** as I have more experience in that not to be misleading.

How to tackle this problem can vary, as sparsity of 1% could mean that these matrices are populated by 99 elements that are 0 and single 1 element *(1.)*. This can be tackled with a much higher accuracy than in case of say 990 zero elements and 10 elements with value of 1 *(2.)*.

1. In case of the former, a reasonable way to go about it to me seems to be using a **softmax** activation function on the **output**, that assures that sum of the values on the output is between 0 and 1, accompanied by **categorical crossentropy** loss and some modern optimizer (I prefer **Adam**).
2. In latter case, we cannot use *softmax*, as there are more 1 valued elements on the output and the sum of the output layer elements therefore cannot be 1. For the same reason we cannot use *categorical crossentropy*. In this case, **sigmoid** activation function on the **output** layer, **binary crossentropy** loss and **Adam** optimizer should be able to easily overcome the great convenience of predicting an all zero vector.

Relevant consideration at very high sparsities here might be attempting to formulate your own loss in a way that correct prediction of *zero values* will be considered within the loss as weighted by accuracy on non-zero values. This way, the neural network will not care about the accuracy at zero values until accuracy is high at non-zero values. Consider a very primitive loss A, defined as,

A=A<sub>1</sub>+A<sub>1</sub>A<sub>0</sub>,

where A<sub>1</sub> is accuracy for non-zero values and A<sub>0</sub> is accuracy for zero values. With this kind of loss, predicting a [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] where a correct value is [0,1,0,0,0,0,0] would yield us an accuracy of 0, which makes former local minima rather steep.